How to create floating window with Ionic framework using Capacitor.js to use the app over other apps
In ionic framework how would I create floating window (similar to GMap) in Android (and/or iOS) preferrably with Capacitor.js (as Cordova slowly deprecating).
If there's possibility of extended support for Cordova plugins too for this case, then list solutions for cordova as well.
A sample image for this is given below:


You need ionic portals feature to create web based windows within the platforms native code. https://ionic.io/docs/portals. without this, it's impossible unless you create your own capacitor plugin

@StackoverBlows I spent last couple of weeks reading ionic portals. I am finding it a bit confusing. Can you please say the exact steps I need to follow? Just keywords would be fine, but I want to know the flow. Like exactly where would I integrate the web based window in the app and how to integrate the ionic portal?

Check Ionic Portal or you will need to do this manually by making a native bridge between your capacitor and the native platform(android and ios), in this case you will need both android, swift and javascript.
Let me know what you reached out to, hope my answer helps!

I understood that it can be done with Ionic Portal, but reading it from last couple of weeks, I am getting confused. I am new to Ionic Portals. Can you please pin point exact portion of the main code I need to add this to, and the exact place where I need to add the portals code. It is the android folder which is being created after capacitor build where I need to update this?
